# Creating a nuget package copying files to the root of the target project

Tags: nuget-package

I'm currently working on creating a NuGet package that requires certain files to be copied during installation. However, I'm facing some issues with the copying process. Firstly, the files are being copied with the read-only attribute, which is causing problems later on. Secondly, they are being copied to a temporary NuGet path that begins with '/.nuget/', which is not ideal. I'm unsure of how to copy these files without the read-only attribute and ensure they are placed in the root folder of the project. Can you offer any guidance or suggestions?

```
<ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="nlog.config">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```